# Android insert into sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I know there is probably a simple thing I'm missing, but I've been beating my head against the wall for the past hour or two.  I have a database for the Android application I'm currently working on (Android v1.6) and I just want to insert a single record into a database table.  My code looks like the following:

```
//Save information to my table
sql =   "INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, field3) " +
        "VALUES (" + field_one + ", " + field_two + ")";
Log.v("Test Saving", sql);
myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

the myDataBase variable is a SQLiteDatabase object that can select data fine from another table in the schema.  The saving appears to work fine (no errors in LogCat) but when I copy the database from the device and open it in sqlite browser the new record isn't there.  I also tried manually running the query in sqlite browser and that works fine.  The table schema for table1 is _id, field1, field2, field3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend using parameters ("?") rather than concatenating your strings into the query. You will run the risk of malformed queries or injection attacks.

Comment: @JimBlackler Can you give a small example of the using `?` for the above query. I googled but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 10):

Your query is invalid because you are providing 2 values for 3 columns. Your raw query should look like:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) " +
    "VALUES (" + field_one + ", " + field_two + ")";
```

although your schema contains three fields. By the way, you can see the log to see the actual error reporting from sqlite.

Comment: I cleaned up the code some and accidentally removed the third field in the values section.  Good catch though.

Answer (score 6):

The right answer is given by the CommonsWare in comments. You should be using execSql() instead of rawQuery(). And it works like a charm.

I thought it would be useful for others, not to have to dig through the comments to find the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since it is a string values you forgot "'" to add...this query will surely work, i tested

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) " + 
"VALUES ('" + field_one + "', '" + field_two + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to use myDataBase.insert() instead of rawQuery() and it's working.  I'm not sure why the actual sql query didn't work though, so if anyone can shed some light on that I'd still appreciate it.

Comment: If what you posted is the exact query, it's because you're specifying 3 fields but only passing 2 values.

Comment: `rawQuery()` is for queries. An `INSERT` statement is not a query. If you want to execute raw SQL that does not return a result set, use `execSQL()`.

Comment: Ah, execSql() is what I needed then.  And yes, I was passing 3 values in my code but it got lost in the code cleanup when I pasted it over here.  Thanks!

@CommonsWare, if you post that as an answer here I will give you credit for solving it.